# How do I go about getting decimals between 0 and 1?

Tags: c#, while-loop

I'm trying to get all of the decimals with 3 digits in them with a while loop until it gets to 1.00.

Like so:

0.00

0.01

0.02

0.03

and so on.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Just read [Custom Number Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should post what you've tried already, but this should get you there:

```
for (double i = 0; i <= 1; i += 0.01)
{
    i = Math.Round(i, 2);

    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

Good feedback in comments.  This should get you there.  Probably not the cleanest approach though.

Comment: You need to include `i=1.0` also, per _OP_ statement.

Comment: This isn't 100% perfect as numbers like `0.01` can't be represented exactly in a `double`.

Comment: The last lines return
0.8
0.810000000000001
0.820000000000001
0.830000000000001
0.840000000000001
0.850000000000001
0.860000000000001
0.870000000000001
0.880000000000001
0.890000000000001
0.900000000000001
0.910000000000001
0.920000000000001
0.930000000000001
0.940000000000001
0.950000000000001
0.960000000000001
0.970000000000001
0.980000000000001
0.990000000000001

Answer (score 4):

As @Mitch recommended in his comment, you should use [`decimal`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) primitive type:

```
for (decimal i = 0m; i <= 1; i += 0.01m)
{
  Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

If you want a numeric real literal to be treated as `decimal`, you need to use the suffix `m` or `M`. Without the suffix `m`, the number is treated as a `double` and generates a compiler error.

Answer (score -2):

```
for(int i=0; i<=100; i++) 
{
   Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:F2}",i/100.0));
}
```

Comment: Not my dv, but op has asked for numbers, specifically for decimals, not strings.